# jQuery validation AJAX form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I'm trying to add validation to my ResetPassword function. validation its work fine, but I got another problem my ResetPassword function not going to work after I add validation.Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx.

HTML code:

```
<div class="PopUpBG">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <h3 class="modal-title">
      <span>Reset PAssword</span>
    </h3>
    <form id="form">

      <input type="email" name="ResetEmail" id="ResetEmail" placeholder="Email Adresse" required/>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send" onclick="ResetPassword(this)"/>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

ResetPassword & validation code:

```
function ResetPassword(e) {

  var email = $("#ResetEmail").val();

  if ($("#form").validate()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  $(".PopUp").html("We have sent mail to you");

  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Account/loginRequestResetPassword",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        Email: email,
      },
      complete: function () {
        console.log("send");
        $(".PopUpBG").fadeOut();
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're *always* exiting the function before you send the AJAX request due to your use of the `return` statement in both conditions of your `if` statement.

Change your logic to only exit the function if the validation fails:

```js
function ResetPassword(e) {
  if (!$("#form").validate())
    return false;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Account/loginRequestResetPassword",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      Email: $("#ResetEmail").val().trim(),
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log("send");
      $(".PopUp").html("We have sent mail to you");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".PopUpBG").fadeOut();
      }, 10000); // fadeout the message after a few seconds
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
    }
  })
}
```

Also note that I amended the logic to only show the successful email message *after* the request completes. Your current code can show the 'email sent' message to the user, even though there is still scope for the function to fail.